# How to fix robots.txt returning a 404 error on non WWW version of the site but no errror on WWW version?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect

I have a wordpress website that's returning a 404 error on url https://example.com/robots.txt but not on url https://www.example.com/robots.txt

I'm already redirecting all traffic from non WWW version to WWW version but somehow when its the /robots.txt its not redirecting.

I've already tried everything I can think off including redirecting it on .htaccess and on functions.php but it's still not working.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think www is the error, I have a WordPress website without www and I can access websiteName/robots.txt.

I think it is a permissions problem I am facing it on another WordPress website and still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation with my robots.txt file, when all non-www website pages including the sitemap file would be redirected to www, but non-www robots.txt page would show a 404 error message. It was working only with www. I just got this problem resolved with the help of my webhosting provider (WP Engine). I see that they have made changes in the wp-config file (in $wpe_all_domains=array) but I can't say if there were other changes made in the webhosting settings. So my suggestion is to review $wpe_all_domains=array (to match your DNS records). If it doesn't help, then contact your webhosting provider and let them know about the issue. They may have other settings they need to check out.